# JavaScript string resolves to false

Tags: javascript

Why both of these resolve to false:

```
console.log("potato" == false); //false
console.log("potato" == true); //false
```

Because what I know when using `==` loose comparison, JS ***coerces*** the operand. Since in JS, *non-empty string should be `true`*, why do above return false above ?

Comment: Here's a useful article on this topic: [http://javascriptweblog.wordpress.com/2011/02/07/truth-equality-and-javascript/](http://javascriptweblog.wordpress.com/2011/02/07/truth-equality-and-javascript/).

Comment: @jakeclarkson your comment should be posted as the right answer. +1 anyway

Comment: @jakeclarkson: I could not understand from there that's why asked here. Clear now, thanks all.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There needs a clarification about the `==` operator. From [ECMA-262 Section 11.9.3](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/files/ECMA-ST/Ecma-262.pdf) the rule6, rule7 and later rule4 determines your result

> rule 6. If Type(x) is Boolean, return the result of the comparison ToNumber(x) == y.
>
> rule 7. If Type(y) is Boolean, return the result of the comparison x == ToNumber(y).
>
> rule 4. If Type(x) is Number and Type(y) is String, return the result of the comparison x == ToNumber(y).

In your context, `false` and `true` will be converted to `0` and `1`, while the `'potato'` will be converted to `NaN`, the comparison expression's value is always `false`.

```
"potato" == false // => "potato" == 0 => NaN == 0
"potato" == true // => "potato" == 1 => NaN == 1
```

Similarly, in `'' == true` comparison, `''` will be converted to `0` while `true` will be converted to `1`, the expression is `false`.

```
'' == false // => 0 == 0
'' == true // => 0 == 1
```

Due to the non-intuitive implementation of `==`,`===` is encouraged to use in comparison.

Answer (score 0):

You mean `Truthy and Falsy Values`:

```
if ("potato") {
   console.log("true")
}
```

But here you compare the String "potato" and a true, JavaScript will try to cast to a comparable thing and that is not the case when you compare the two values you have.